# iOS - Core Data model Conflict With Mail Framework?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmanagedobject, messageui

I have a Core Data object, `Account`, represented as a subclass of `NSManagedObject`:

```
@interface Account : NSManagedObject
```

My entire app has been developing just fine, however, when I add the `MessageUI.framework` so I can get a compose email view controller, all hell breaks loose. The app links and compiles fine, and runs just fine. Until, that is, I start interfacing with my previously working `Account` objects. Then, I start getting these:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: '"Account" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x202b012 ... 0x2385)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This particular one of which was caused by:

```
// we need to insert a new account
Account *newAccount = [NSEntityDescription
                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[Account entityName] 
                            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Now, I'm guessing that there is some class in the `MessageUI.framework` causing the conflict, but I have a few questions:

1. The app compiles and runs just fine, no compile-time name conflicts
2. The other components in the framework seem to be prefix-namespaced (ie: `MFMailComposeViewController`), so should the theoretical account not be `MFAccount`?
3. I'm not even doing an `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` or the slightly tighter `#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>`, the latter of which I inspected and saw no definition of `Account`, so I'm not sure why the possible conflicts would even be loaded.
4. Just to be certain, I re-generated my Core Data classes, and reset all simulator settings, still no dice.
5. Removing the Framework from the project and build settings immediately fixes the issue.

Comment: Have you tried renaming your NSManagedObject subclass?

Comment: @geraldWilliam: Whilst I assume that that will remedy the situation, I'd rather not namespace my models if not necessary. I really asked this question because I want to know what I'm missing, as all of my investigation has led to dead ends, and if this situation or another like it ever pops up again, I'd like to be able to solve it quickly and with intuition.

Comment: Sure that makes sense. It's just that when I've run into a similar situation where I had name my managed object subclass "Message", I just renamed it and the problem was solved. Moving forward, I'm just naming all of my managed object subclasses with a prefix to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Josh did prefixing your model object names resolve this?

Comment: @CarlVeazey: I did end up prefixing them yes, after a bit of further futile research. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had this happen to me, with this is exact framework (the class was called `Broadcaster`). In this case, the private `Message` framework is linked by `MessageUI`, and this framework provides the `Account` implementation.

You can verify that the MessageUI framework loads an `Account` class by making a new project, and in the app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, add the following code:

```
NSString *account = @"Account";
Class accountClass = NSClassFromString(account);
NSLog(@"accountClass = %@",accountClass);
```

On a fresh project this will print `accountClass = (null)` but after adding MessageUI it will print `accountClass = Account`.

Furthermore, if you use `class-dump` on the private `Message` framework, you'll see the interface declaration for `Account`.

Now, you list 5 items in your post as questions, I'll try to address them

1. I don't know enough about the link-time process for working with
   Frameworks to say for sure, but I suspect the `Message` framework is weakly linked and thus won't cause a duplicate symbol error at link time.
2. The public facing ones are named correctly but some undocumented
   ones aren't. Also, the conflicting class is in the private `Message` framework.
3. That doesn't matter at all. The compiler will use `#import`, but at
   run time, all the classes are loaded with your application and there
   is no "visibility" or anything like that enforced in the runtime.
4. N/A
5. Consistent with other evidence

As far as a course of action, I just renamed my model class to have a prefix. I'm not aware of any other solution.

Comment: Yes, renaming the "Account" entity fixes the issue.

Comment: you can add "OutgoingMessage" to the forbidden list too, at least on ios6. ouch.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the message framework is not the problem at all.  Stuff like this can happen unexpectedly with core data, such as when you change the model somehow.  Try cleaning the build, deleting your simulator / hardware installed test apps, and running again.  The reason geraldWilliam suggested renaming it, I think, is to fix this problem, but it might not be necessary to rename anything

Check out this thread: [Could not locate NSManagedObjectModel for Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039660/could-not-locate-nsmanagedobjectmodel-for-entity)