# Prefixing CoreData generated classes

Tags: core-data, xcode4.6, xcdatamodel

In my XCode project I have two data models (.xcdatamodel) and want to generate NSManagedObject-derived classes for the entities in each of these models. The problem is that both models contain an entity with the same name.  How can I get these classes generated with a prefix so as to avoid link errors due to name collisions similar to that described in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575611/ios-core-data-model-conflict-with-mail-framework)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give them different class names, that's all. Entity names and class names don't have to be the same. The generated classes will use whatever name you provide.

For example, if you had an entity `Person`, you could add a prefix `Foo` to its generated class name:

[image]

When you generated classes for this entity, you would get FooPerson.h and FooPerson.m. Use different prefixes in different models, and you get different classes.

On a related note, you'll get much better results if you use [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to generate your classes than if you use Xcode's built-in class generation. It's a lot more flexible, and it makes it **much** easier to keep your generated classes up to date if you change the model.